# Laravel 5.0 form validation unique per relation

Tags: php, laravel

I have a model Mailgroup with a one to many relation for Individual.

Now when I create a new Individual I want to make sure that that Individual is unique for that specific mailgroup.

In my form validation I did this:

```
'individual_email' => 'required|unique:individuals|max:255',
```

This works good but it checks the entire database so if that individual exist for 1 mailgroup it will says that it's already in use.

Now I read in the laravel documentation you can add where clausules in your validation like this:

> 'email' => 'unique:users,email_address,NULL,id,account_id,1'
>
> In the rule above, only rows with an account_id of 1 would be included in the unique check.

So I wanna change my rule to something like this:

```
'individual_email' => 'required|unique:individuals,individual_email,NULL,id,mailgroup_id,'.$data['mailgroup_id'].'|max:255'
```

But the problem is how can I access my form post data? because $data is not recognized.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try below:

```
'individual_email' => 'required|unique:individuals,individual_email,NULL,id,mailgroup_id,'.$this->get('mailgroup_id').'|max:255'
```

Answer (score 1):

Do this via [Request](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/validation#form-request-validation) class:

```
use Illuminate\Validation\Rule;

/**
* Get the validation rules that apply to the request.
*
* @return array
*/
public function rules()
{
    return [
        'individual_email' => [
            'required',
            Rule::unique('individuals', 'individual_email')
               ->where('mailgroup_id', $this->get('mailgroup_id')),
        ]
    ];
}
```